# CAtlMap use CString as a key

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, atl

For simplicity this problem I created new MPF Project in Visual Studio by Wizard. I would like to use `CAtlMap` with `CString` as a key parameter. I included `<atlcoll.h>` header and when I tried to compile the following code:

```
CAtlMap<CString, double> myMap;
CString strMyKey = L"MyKey";

myMap.SetAt(strMyKey, 76.8);
```

I received this error:

```
'<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const CString' to 'ULONG_PTR'
```

When I used simple types (e.g. `int`) instead of `CString` project was compiled without any errors. Is it possible to use `CString` as in the example above? Maybe I missed some include files, which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `CMap` instead of `CAtlMap` as it is outdated/deprecated (ATL and MFC collection classes have been unified). You should define your map like this:

```
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, double, double> myMap;
```

Please also consider using `operator[]` instead of `SetAt()` for better readability of your code.

If for some reason (compatibility with some old/legacy project) you have to use `CAtlMap` you have to do this: `CAtlMap<CString, double, CStringElementTraits<CString> > map;`

Comment: I must using `CAtlMap`, because I am working with old project and this is the main requirement. I moved some classes form one library (dll) to another and this classes stopped to compile. I am trying to repair of the moved files.

Comment: Try `CAtlMap<CString, double, CStringElementTraits<CString> > map;`

Comment: There is nothing in the headers or MSDN that indicates CAtlMap is deprecated.  In fact, it was created after CMap (ATL is much newer than MFC) and CMap is not available in ATL unless you include MFC headers.  ATL programs SHOULD use CAtlMap, MFC applications may choose.  You will need the string traits though since MFC uses a specialization of CString that is not compatible with ATL's collections.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 `CAtlMap` class is suitable for the mentioned use and does not give compiler errors. You can create a console application checking box for ATL support, and this code compiles and works well.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlcoll.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CAtlMap<CString, double> myMap;
    CString strMyKey = L"MyKey";
    myMap.SetAt(strMyKey, 76.8);
    return 0;
}
```

As you mentioned you are working with legacy project, it might so happen it has a copy of older version of ATL, such as ATL 3.0. Indeed, older ATL could have such problem and if this is the problem you perhaps need to switch the code to newer ATL collection classes.